# GWT: redirect user on window close

Tags: gwt, redirect

I need to intercept when the user navigates away from the page, to redirect him somewhere else.

This will be used to manage a sales flow to avoid going back.

We tried something like

```
Window.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler<Window>() {

  @Override
  public void onClose(CloseEvent<Window> event) {

    ...
    Window.open("main");

  }
});
```

but this only works on Firefox.
On Chrome the code is executed but there is no redirection. If I change to "_blank" then a new window opens with the given URL but this is not the required behaviour.

Comment: Browsers tend to try to do all that's possible to avoid users being locked in a site / page. I have no idea what your use-case is, but I certainly wouldn't like the way you're trying to solve it.

Comment: I don't like it either, but the client requested this approach.

This is to avoid "jumping" between the steps of a sales process. If the user for example clicks the back button will be redirected to the first step.

Comment: Then maybe you just need to handle "history" within your app differently? If all the steps but the first share the same "history token", then clicking the back button will get you back to the first step (BTW, `onClose` wouldn't handle move between "history tokens" in the same GWT app) If you have separate HTML pages, then you could possibly handle it on the server-side, it'd then really depend on how you navigate between pages in the nominal case, but it wouldn't be impossible I believe (once again, a very bad experience for everyone, but not technically impossible).

Comment: I am actually pushing for a different solution (cleaning the sales process), but I would still like to know why on Chrome the redirection doesn't work while on Firefox it does. Couldn't find any docs about that.

Comment: I added a possible explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this behavior is per-spec (HTML5):

> If there is a preexisting attempt to navigate the browsing context, and the source browsing context is the same as the browsing context being navigated, and that attempt is currently running the unload a document algorithm, and the origin of the URL of the resource being loaded in that navigation is not the same origin as the origin of the URL of the resource being loaded in this navigation, then abort these steps without affecting the preexisting attempt to navigate the browsing context.

— *Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#navigate*